# Loop through JavaScript array and exclude the array itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to loop through a JS object parsed from JSON code in `[this.props.dataPro.links]`:

```
 "links" : 
[ "/static/media/0.jpg",
  "/static/media/1.jpg",
  "/static/media/1.jpg" ],
```

I am inserting these links by array key into an images object:

```
_getStaticImages() {
    let images = [this.props.dataPro.links]
    for (var key in images) {
      if (images.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var obj = images[key];
         for (var prop in obj) {
           if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            images.push({
            original: obj[prop],
            thumbnail:obj[prop]
          });
        }
      }
     }
   }


    return images;
  }
```

As a result I get an empty returned object at the beginning of my return object, when I do a console.log on the `images` response it seems I also return the array object itself:

```
[Array[3], Object, Object, Object]
0:Array[4]
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
```

How can I sort loop through my array and exclude the array itself?

Comment: I'm still not understanding why you are iterating with a `for .. in` loop.  Why not just iterate by dereferencing the array `links[i]` or use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Comment: @zero298 He's using `for .. in` because `links` is a property

Comment: @Aaron but it looks like the value of links is an array and that is what he is looping over.

Comment: @Aaron But he is iterating `links` and `links` is defined: `"links": [...]`.  So `links` itself is an array and can be iterated as such.

Comment: @zero298 Sorry I am a rookie to development, I searched around for the best way to loop through an array, but thank you very much for your answer I will see if this is an easier way!

Comment: show how your array should look like?

Comment: @zer298 You are correct, but he probably used it because he saw that `links` is a property. As for looping an array... a standard `for` is enough.

Comment: @Aravind My return object should simply be `[Object, Object, Object]` with a key of `original` and `thumbnail` in each object.

Comment: sample data please

Comment: @Ven What don't you understand?  OP defined `links` as an array in his first snippet.  Then he iterates it like an object.

Comment: I don't what you're talking about with your for in and all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the initial array to your output `let images = [this.props.dataPro.links]`. Instead, you could use Array.map ideally here:

```js
var linkObj = {
  "links": [
    "/static/media/0.jpg",
    "/static/media/1.jpg",
    "/static/media/1.jpg"
  ]
};

function getStaticImages() {
  let output = linkObj.links.map(imgUrl => {
    return {
      original: imgUrl,
      thumbnail: imgUrl
    }
  });
  return output;
}

console.log(getStaticImages());
```

Comment: Using `map()`. _Chapeu bas_. I have to remember this approach.

Comment: @Jonathan Arrow functions are not supported in IE..? May be worth considering

Comment: IE <= Arrow functions?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and do something like this:

```
getStaticImages(imageArray) {
  return imageArray.map(function(img) {
    return {
      original: img.whateverPropMapsToOriginal,
      thumbnail: img.whateverPropMapsToThumbnail,
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var images = [];
for(var i = 0; i < this.props.dataPro.links.length;i++)
{
   images.push({
     original: this.props.dataPro.links[i],
     thumbnail: this.props.dataPro.links[i]
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for why do you have array as first element first, this line:

```
let images = [this.props.dataPro.links]
```

in which you create array `images` with first element of array that you are going to iterate through.

To create an empty array, don’t put any values inside:

```
let images = []; // nothing inside
```

As for iterating itself. Given that `this.props.dataPro.links` is already array, to iterate through it you should go like that:

```
var myArray = this.props.dataPro.links; // so we don’t need to type it later
var images = []; // we’re creating *empty* table
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    console.log('Item', i, myArray[i]);
    images.push({
        original: item,
        thumbnail: item
    });
}
```

That’s the old way of doing it. If you are supporting from IE9 up, then you can use function [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var images = [];
this.props.dataPro.links.foreach(function (item, index) {
    console.log('Item', index, item);
    images.push({
        original: item,
        thumbnail: item
    });
}
```

Don’t use the second solution, if you want to optionally break iterating through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your `for` loop?

```
for (let i = 1; i > obj.length; i++) {
  if (obj[i]) {
    images.push({
      original: obj[prop],
      thumbnail: obj[prop]
    })
  }
}
```

This skips the `0th` element of the array (the object you want to skip), but still pushes the images you want.